# Xcode :Get Data From Database device

Tags: ios, nsarray, uicollectionview

I'm beginner IOS developer Please guide me someone about 'How can I get data from database only I have'
I have 2 class for this `MainViewController` and `BookViewController`
this one is work fine for offline mode can show data only i have.

MainViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    db = [[DBManager alloc]init];
    [db initWithDB];
    bookArray = [db getBookData];
}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    _databaseVersion = [[bookArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]bookVersion];

    NSLog(@"%f",_databaseVersion);
    BookCell *bookcell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ReuseCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return bookcell;

}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [bookArray count];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}
```

This `MainViewController` is working 
but when I'm send data like this to `BookViewController`

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{


        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"course1"]){
            BookViewController *controller = (BookViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

            [controller setBookArray:bookArray];
            controller.checkType = @"1";
            controller.statusMode = statusMode;
            controller.databaseVersion = _databaseVersion;

        }
}
```

but bookArray is not work for `BookViewController`

BookViewController.m

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);


    BookCell *bookcell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ReuseCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    BookCell *cell = (BookCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     NSInteger row= indexPath.row;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[bookList objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]coverURL]];

            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


                bookcell.bookCover.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                bookcell.bookCover.alpha = 0.5f;
                bookcell.bookDetailLabel.hidden = NO;
                        NSLog(@"Row == %d ",row);

         if ([[bookList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]bookVersion] > [[bookArray   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]bookVersion] && [[bookArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]bookVersion] > 0) {
           bookcell.bookCover.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
           bookcell.bookCover.alpha = 1.0f;
           bookcell.bookDetailLabel.hidden = NO;
           bookcell.bookDetailLabel.text = @"Update";


          }

                });
        });

    }
    return bookcell;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [bookList count];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}
```

`//bookList is data from Webservice and bookArray is data from database.`

but I don't know why I can't use data from database
I'm try like this `[[bookArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]bookVersion];` in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` on `BookViewController.m` but bookArray alway crash because bookArry have only one data is work if I go like this `[[bookArray objectAtIndex:0]bookVersion];` will get one data and not crash but I want to use

```
    if([[bookList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]bookVersion] > [[bookArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]bookVersion])
{ .... }
```

but this one alway crash because have `[[bookList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]bookVersion]` have 10 data inside on webservice but `[[bookArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]bookVersion]` have only one data Please help me how to get `[[bookArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]bookVersion]` data and not crash if don't have data will show `null`  Please please please.

crash on this `[[bookArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]bookVersion]`

```
 NSString *testData = [[bookArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]downloadFlag];
 NSLog(@"test flag %@",testData);


2014-01-20 11:14:29.837 GreenAcademy PowerShelf[596:60b] test flag 1
2014-01-20 11:14:29.842 GreenAcademy PowerShelf[596:60b] -------------------------
2014-01-20 11:14:29.844 GreenAcademy PowerShelf[596:60b] test flag 1
2014-01-20 11:14:29.849 GreenAcademy PowerShelf[596:60b] -------------------------
2014-01-20 11:14:29.851 GreenAcademy PowerShelf[596:60b] test flag 1
2014-01-20 11:14:29.854 GreenAcademy PowerShelf[596:60b] -------------------------
2014-01-20 11:14:29.863 GreenAcademy PowerShelf[596:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2e349f4b 0x38a1b6af 0x2e280533 0xb6911 0x30b1de65 0x30b1c5d9 0x30b18921 0x30abcda3 0x30743c6b 0x3073f47b 0x3073f30d 0x3073ed1f 0x3073eb2f 0x3073885d 0x2e3151cd 0x2e312b71 0x2e312eb3 0x2e27dc27 0x2e27da0b 0x32f51283 0x30b21049 0x80b7d 0x38f23ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` in `BookViewController.m` is very curious, though. You're referencing `shelfcell`, but don't show us that. After `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` you set `cell` (I'm guessing this was supposed to be  the `shelfcell`) using `cellForItemAtIndexPath` but that construct doesn't make sense unless you're doing that _inside_ the block to dispatch back to the main queue from the background queue. It's also unclear why you're calling `[db initWithDB]` in that background queue.

Comment: I'm edit my questions now help me please. @Rob Thank you very much I'm  write wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want your code to generate an exception when you try to access an item beyond the array of items, check the `count` property first. Thus, rather than:

```
NSInteger row = indexPath.row
if ([[bookList objectAtIndex:row] bookVersion] > [[bookArray objectAtIndex:row] bookVersion])
{ .... }
```

You can just add a check of the `count` property, first:

```
if ([bookArray count] >= (row + 1) && [[bookList objectAtIndex:row] bookVersion] > [[bookArray objectAtIndex:row] bookVersion])
{ .... }
```

or, perhaps a little more concise, using the new array subscript notation:

```
if ([bookArray count] >= (row + 1) && [bookList[row] bookVersion] > [bookArray[row] bookVersion])
{ .... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindness,I can't thank you enough. This perfect.Thanks teacher.

Comment: Please help me again. why I can't show bookCover bookID = 4 if I not download bookID = 3 first. I'm use this code for show some book `if ([bookArray count] >= (row + 1) && [[bookList objectAtIndex:row] bookVersion] > [[bookArray objectAtIndex:row] bookVersion]&& [[[bookList objectAtIndex:row]bookID] isEqualToString:[[bookArray objectAtIndex:row]bookID]]){..}`  please guide me.

Comment: @user2180698 It's hard to say, because it's not entirely clear what your app's "model" is (and, no offense, your question is pretty confusing, including lots of irrelevant stuff, but ironically not enough stuff to answer these sorts of questions; and it's already so much of a mess that I hesitate to invite you to add more code; lol).

Comment: Your root problem seems to be "how to I coordinate these two separate arrays", to which the right answer is probably "you shouldn't have two separate arrays". Either have a single one which you update as you go along, or the second structure should be a dictionary keyed by the book id, rather than being an array. Either approach, you could then update the records in a non-sequential manner, and it would work fine. But arrays really work best when you're adding and inquiring about items in a sequential fashion.

Comment: Thank you so much,ok I'll try. Thanks again you code is very helpful.